# Use an Access Forms Unbound text box as a Field filter in a table

Tags: sql, vba, reference, ms-access-2013

## Access 2013 - Reference an Unbound text box on a Form

I am currently trying to use an unbound text box `[Text161]` on a Form name `[DCM_Gap_Servers]` to sort information through a table. I want the query that I created to be able to take the users input from `[DCM_Gap_Servers]![Text161]` as the field that is being sorted from the table names 'Server'.

This is the SQL I am using right now in the query:

```
SELECT * FROM Servers WHERE "Forms![DCM_Gap_Servers]![Text161]" IS NULL
```

** I have already Tried:

```
"Forms![DCM_Gap_Servers]![Text161]" ; (Forms![DCM_Gap_Servers]![Text161]); Forms.[DCM_Gap_Servers]![Text161]
```

This will work at any time if I replace the Text Box reference with the actual Field name I am using, but since there are hundreds of combinations of fields, I need the reference to work.

I have looked all over, and I can't seem to find the correct answer. I am willing to do it in VBA if needed, whatever it takes to get the filtering done correctly.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It is:

```
SELECT * FROM Servers WHERE Forms.[DCM_Gap_Servers].[Text161] IS NULL
```

but that will just select all records whenever your textbox is Null.

So it rather is:

```
SELECT * FROM Servers WHERE SomeField = Forms.[DCM_Gap_Servers].[Text161]
```

To use the form value as a field name, you must use concatenated SQL:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Servers WHERE " & Forms![DCM_Gap_Servers]![Text161].Value & " IS NULL"
```

This you might pass to the SQL property of an existing query object:

```
MyQueryDef.SQL = strSQL
```

Or:

```
Constant SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM Servers WHERE {0} IS NULL"
FieldName = Forms![DCM_Gap_Servers]![Text161].Value
MyQueryDef.SQL = Replace(strSQL, "{0}", FieldName)
```

Of course, take care the the field name isn't a zero length string.

Comment: Unfortunately this still does not work. When I attempt to run the query, I get a "Enter Parameter Value" box that appears. Seems like I don't think this is the answer.

Comment: Still don't know what you wish to accomplish. If filtering on a field, replace `SomeField` with the name of that field.

Comment: That is where my problem lies. I am trying to have one query for each table, but each table has over 25 fields. I am trying to avoid having to create a unique query for each field name, which is why I am trying to have the text box change the value in the query so I can use one query instead. Im sorry If my question is a little confusing, it seems to be a unique situation.

Comment: See my expanded answer, please.

Comment: So I am assuming you are intending for this to be done using VBA? I am trying to follow, but when I use VBA I continue to get an error that an 'Object is Required'. I am creating a button on my form, and then applying that code to the button so that when a text is entered into that box (field name), the macro will run the code to apply the filter. Do you mind telling me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, you can't use parameters as field names in a query, so you have to modify the SQL of a query or create it form scratch. The code above is just the essential part; you will have to specify which query to modify, or you can build the SQL string and use it directly as RecordSource for a form.